# parse values while configuring options

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm using .NET Core and want to configure my options. Based on this sample class

```
public class MySettings
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> Mapping { get; set; }
}
```

I added a mapping to the appsettings.json file

```
{
  "MySettings": {
    "Mapping": {
      "9454545": "agf51528gfhdfg",
      "13544": "bfds28745hfghsdfghd"
    }
  }
}
```

but as you can see the keys are of type string, not integers. It is not possible for me to change the property names to numbers because then I get the error

> JSON property names should be strings. Numeric property names are not
> allowed in JSON

So when calling this in the startup file

```
IConfigurationSection mySettingsSection = configuration.GetSection("MySettings");
services.Configure<MySettings>(mySettingsSection);
```

the field `Mapping` will have 0 items because it is not able to parse the JSON keys to integers automatically. Is there a way I can tell .NET Core to parse those string keys to integers and fill up the dictionary?

Comment: why dont you use `Mapping` as an array instead of object?

Comment: I updated my question. The IDs don't represent indices :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can tell .NET Core to parse those string keys to integers and fill up the dictionary?

Unfortunately, there is **no** way to achieve that.

**Reason**

First, internally `ConfigurationProvider` use a `IDictionary<string, string>` to hold key-value pair of configuration settings ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/src/ConfigurationProvider.cs#L30)).

```
/// <summary>
/// The configuration key value pairs for this provider.
/// </summary>
protected IDictionary<string, string> Data { get; set; }
```

Second, when `JsonConfigurationProvider` try to parse JSON file (appsettings.json in your case) and populate that `Data` property, the parsing result, without doubt, is `IDictionary<string, string>` type ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json/src/JsonConfigurationFileParser.cs#L20)).

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> Parse(Stream input)
    => new JsonConfigurationFileParser().ParseStream(input);

private IDictionary<string, string> ParseStream(Stream input)
{
    // Exclude implementation
}
```

Last, when you call `services.Configure<MySettings>(mySettingsSection)`, under the hood it calls `Bind` method to populate `MySettings` object by matching property name (`string`) against configuration key (`string`) ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/src/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L107)).

```
/// <summary>
/// Attempts to bind the given object instance to configuration values by matching property names against configuration keys recursively.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="configuration">The configuration instance to bind.</param>
/// <param name="instance">The object to bind.</param>
/// <param name="configureOptions">Configures the binder options.</param>
public static void Bind(this IConfiguration configuration, object instance, Action<BinderOptions> configureOptions)
```

So, inside .NET Core framework, from building configuration key-value pairs to binding configuration to custom object, the data flow is always around `IDictionary<string, string>` type. Moreover, there is no custom binding options to let you do any kind of data type conversion.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm I think you need workaround because cannot allow int at json file.
Something like this:

```
var mySettingsSection = 
configuration.GetSection("MySettings").Get<Dictionary<string, string>>().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<int, string>(int.Parse(x.Key), x.Value));
```

Comment: This does not return the section itself. It just returns the converted dictionary :(

Answer (score -1):

You have two options,
First one is to change the config file to int,string. For example:

```
{
  "MySettings": {
    "Mapping": {
      1: "a",
      2: "b"
    }
  }
}
```

Second possibility is to create another properties in `MySettings` class that will be with correct type (Dictionary<string,string>) and in `Mapping` field you can do a kind of conversion in the getter.

```
public class MySettings
{
    public Dictionary<int, string> Mapping => Config.ToDictionary(a => Int32.Parse(a.Key), a => a.Value);

    public Dictionary<int, string> Config { get; set; }
}
```

If you will call Mapping multiple type you can save the conversion result once and not recalculate it in every call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The first option does not work, it says `json property names should be strings. numeric property names are not allowed in json`

Comment: np :) I think your second solution should work but I really don't like it. I was hoping for a parsing configuration or something like that